# Postgres, Large Arrays & MVCC

Tags: postgresql

I'm contemplating the following schema:

```
create table pool
(
    id integer not null
        constraint pool_pk
            primary key,
    contact_index integer not null,
    contact_id integer[]
);
```

Basically a large array of integers, which could be as many as 1 million - and are only written once, and an index value into them that is updated over time.

My question is:

If I update the `contact_index` field will that cause a rewrite of the entire row, or is the large array field stored "off page" somehow?

Comment: "*If I update the contact_index field will that cause a rewrite of the entire row,*" yes, it will. You are better off with a properly normalized model using a one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of 1e6 integers will be stored off page in [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html).  If you update something else in the row, the TOAST data does not get copied for the new row version, just the TOAST pointer does.